# Default background for button container view?

Tags: android, android-layout

Im looking for the default background showed and style in the layoutview with the two buttons in the photo below. In what android resource can i find it?

[image: Layout]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be this one:

[image: Bottom bar]

I found it in the res folder in the SDK. This one is from drawable-hdpi for SDK level8. The file is called bottom_bar.png

Comment: Never mind found the answer! =)

    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"